# TensorFlow: Unable to evaluate / obtain tensor's value in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

def weight_variable(shape):
initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)


W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( 
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
      print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

  print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
      x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

above is the code for multilayer Convolutional Neural Network straight from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/get_started/mnist/pros

I've been trying to obtain the values in h_conv1 and h_conv2, and I've tried using

```
get_value = h_conv1.eval() or h_conv1.eval(session=sess)
```

both are not successful, I even tried setting name in h_conv1 and get it by using

```
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1, name='example')

test = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("example:0")
```

and still it wasn't successful. 
However, it's easy to extract the values of W_conv1 by using

```
weights = W_conv1.eval()
```

and it will shows up in Spyder's variable explorer as a numpy array and I can do whatever I want with it.

I was wondering is there any other way to get the h_conv1 value, so I can do some processing steps on those values before feeding it to the next operation.

Comment: You have to specify what you mean by "not successful". You are probably getting some error messages and you should include them with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running into the problem I expect you are, the problem is that the weights you are printing out succesfully are tensorflow variables (meaning their values get stored as part of the session), but h_conv1 is an operation, meaning it has an output that is defined as a function of its input. Since those inputs end up routing back to placeholder variables, and you're not giving any placeholder variables when you eval the operation, it fails with InvalidArgumentOperation.

What I'm guessing what you're looking for is the value of the output the last time you ran the training operation. To get this, the approach I got working is simply to attach a `tf.Print` operation to that node, and then evaluating that at the same time as I run the training operation. So in your graph definition you have something like this:

```
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_conv1_printop = tf.Print(h_conv1, [h_conv1])
```

Then replace this line:

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

with this line:

```
_, hconv1_out = sess.run([train_step, h_conv1_printop], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
print(hconv1_out)
```

Basically, attach a print Op to the relu Op you want to see the output of, and then evaluate that Op at the same time you are running the rest of the session so that it gets filled in with the value.

Hopefully that makes sense and solves your issue, always helpful to review the docs on [graphs and sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/graphs) since this is all a common point confusion.

Comment: Can it be evaluate and pass its values to numpy array during session run time?
I need to do that because the function I'm using only takes in numpy array instead of tensor.
I need it to convert it to numpy array, pass it into the function and the function processes it and outputs numpy array, I will convert it back to tensor by using tf.convert_to_tensor and feed it to the next layer.